# Git pre-commit hooks per directory

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

How do I format a `.pre-commit-config.yaml` so it's different depending on my directory?

My project has different directories. One directory is a UI directory with a `package.json` and Django files. Another one is a Python package, which does not have a `package.json`.

I would like to run `eslint` only on the UI directory, not on the Python package directory as it has no Javascript files.

Currently when I run it at the root it says:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/xxx/package.json'
```

My `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file looks something like:

```
fail_fast: true
repos:
- repo: git://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
  rev: v0.9.2
  hooks:
    ...

- repo: local
  hooks:
  - id: eslint
    name: eslint-local
    entry: npm run lint
    language: system
    types: [javascript]
    exclude: >
            (?x)^(
                .+\.config\.js|
                server\.js|
                \.eslintrc\.js
            )$
    pass_filenames: true
```

Comment: changing directory isn't supported "natively" -- you can find some workarounds on the issue tracker: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+monorepo+is%3Aclosed (disclaimer: I'm the author)

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute commands in bash/other and change directory yourself! That's what worked best for me.

For example:

```yaml
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: go-unit-tests
        name: run go test s(go test)
        language: system
        entry: bash -c 'cd subdir && exec go test ./...'
        pass_filenames: false
        types: [go]
        files: ^subdir/
```

or if you're running Python tests:

```yaml
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pytest
        name: pytest
        entry: sh -c 'cd text2sql-backend && PYTHONPATH=. poetry run pytest .'
        language: system
        types: [python]
        pass_filenames: false
        stages: [commit]
        exclude: ".*pb2(_grpc)?.py(i)?$|__init__.py"
```